# How can I use form-builder for Wt or intagrate to Qt Creator/Designer?

Tags: qt, web-applications, qt-creator, qt-designer, wt

How can I use form-builder for Wt with custom size and position of widgets, or intagrate to Qt Creator/Designer?

1. As known Wt ([C++ Web Toolkit](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)) is a C++ library for developing web applications **with a Qt like API**, and a very powerful functionality for building Web applications, example: https://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/graphics-charts/3d-category-chart
2. Also Qt has a very user friendly form-builder in Qt Creator/Designer with many widgets, spaces and layouts, which can be used to **relative position of widgets** for different sizes of form when form is resized:

[image]

Also there is [WtDesigner](https://github.com/juangburgos/WtDesigner) for Wt on Windows/Linux, but for Wt-widgets:

- it can't change widget position
- can't change widget width
- can't change column name on table
- can't change size of table columns, etc...

[image]

QtDesigner vs WtDesigner:

- QtDesigner can place widgets in any absolute or relative position and any size which I set (and relative position will moves widgets for better display on any screen resolution)
- WtDesigner can place widgets only one under one, only with maximum width

Comment: Are you sure that Wt's API allows you to do what you want? It might be that WtDesigner simply reflects what the API lets you do.

Comment: @Kuba Obe There are at least 3 approaches to set position of widgets: **1.** `void Wt::WBorderLayout::addWidget(WWidget *widget, Position position)` https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WBorderLayout.html#af7667b3d486dc649a7ed0c56f8c06206 **2.** Wt -> existing HTML `div id="chat"></div>` & `chat.emit(chat, 'login', 'koen');` https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/blog/2010/12/17/widgetset_mode_and_cross_origin_requests **3.** `<p>${name-edit}</p>` & `Wt::WTemplate *t = ...; t->bindWidget("name-edit", new Wt::WLineEdit());` https://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/layout/html-templates

Comment: There's WtDesigner, and then there's DesignerWt. I haven't used any of them, maybe one is worth more than the other? I prefer CSS for styling a Wt application.